# WPF onbutton click add a string in a string list?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I have a xaml.
In that xaml their is a button.
how can i programm it that
If i click the button it adds a string in a string list on a class in the projekt.

```
my class:
class Lager
{
    static public  List<string> Zutaten { get ; set; }
}

button:
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string anytext = "random text";
        Lager.Zutaten.Add(anytext);
    }
```

Comment: What is your error message ? What is not working as expected ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF isn't really designed the way you are trying to use it here. I'd strongly recommend you start with a few wpf specific mvvm tutorials.

But to answer your question:
From your provided code it just looks like you forgot to instantiate the "Zutaten" List:

```
public static class Lager
{
    static public List<string> Zutaten { get ; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```